# ASP.NET - How to create radio button maxtrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, matrix, radiobuttonlist

I want create a radio button maxtrix like below picture!

[image]

I was tried use Repeate, but data is different between row and column. So i can't set datasource for repeater. Have way to group 2 list, and set datasource for Repeater, show data int Repeater by call `Eval("row")`, `Eval("column")` and `Eval("mark")`

```
var lstMatrixAnswer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(json); //Get from json format
    var row = lstMatrixAnswer.row.Select(p => p.row).ToList(); //Row datasource
    var col= lstMatrixAnswer.column.Select(p => p.answer + "///" + p.mark).ToList(); //Column datasource (i want radio values is "mark")

public class AnswerCol
{
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public int mark { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerRow
{
    public string row { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public List<AnswerRow> row { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerCol> column { get; set; }
}
```

//This is repeater, but i make sure it is impossible.

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAnswer" runat="server">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable" id="tblObject">
                                            <thead>
                                                <th style="vertical-align: middle"><%#Eval("col")%></th>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <%#Eval("answer") %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input id="Radio1" type="radio" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("mark") %>' />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

== Thank for reading ==

Comment: Could you show the cshtml you are using to display this?

Comment: I have updated, but i make sure it is impossible

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this way way back only using asp.net and javascript
Here i am posting only a little part , hope its enough for you to keep things going

```
<table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="qoptions">
                     <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                                <td align="left" width="15%">Function</td>
                                <td style="color:#b91d47; font-size:large;font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Highly Dissatisfied</td>
                                <td style="color:#b91d47; font-size:large;font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Dissatisfied</td>
                                <td style="color:#b91d47; font-size:large;font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Satisfied</td>
                                <td style="color:#b91d47; font-size:large;font-weight:bold; text-align:center">Highly Satisfied</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;" align="right"><span style="padding-right:75px">Comments <span class="instructions">(optional)</span></span></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr  style="background-color:#FDE6EA" id="BST"> <%--id="F0Q1"--%>
                                <td align="left" id="F0Name" >BST</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbQ1F0_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q1F0" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbQ1F0_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q1F0" /></td>
                                <td ><asp:RadioButton ID="rbQ1F0_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q1F0" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rbQ1F0_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q1F0" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ1F0" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);" />&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q1F0Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="altrow" id="F1Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F1Name">F1</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F1_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F1" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F1_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F1" /></td>
                                <td ><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F1_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F1" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F1_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F1" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"  />&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F1Val" Value="" />

                              </tr>
                            <tr id="F2Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F2Name" >F2</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F2_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F2" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F2_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F2" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F2_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F2" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F2_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F2" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);" />&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F2Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="altrow" id="F3Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F3Name" >F3</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F3_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F3" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F3_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F3" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F3_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F3" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F3_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F3" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F3Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="F4Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F4Name" >F4</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F4_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F4" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F4_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F4" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F4_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F4" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F4_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F4" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F4" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F4Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="altrow" id="F5Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F5Name" >F5</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F5_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F5" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F5_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F5" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F5_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F5" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F5_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F5" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F5" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F5Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="F6Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F6Name" >F6</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F6_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F6" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F6_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F6" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F6_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F6" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F6_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F6" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F6" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F6Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="altrow" id="F7Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F7Name" >F7</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F7_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F7" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F7_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F7" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F7_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F7" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F7_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F7" /></td>
                                <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F7" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F7Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="F8Q2">
                                <td align="left" id="F8Name" >F8</td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F8_1" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F8" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F8_2" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F8" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F8_3" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F8" /></td>
                                <td><asp:RadioButton ID="Q2F8_4" runat="server" GroupName="Q2F8" /></td>
                                 <td align="right"><asp:TextBox ID="txtQ2F8" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="35" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" onChange="javascript:Count(this);"/>&nbsp;</td>
                                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="Q2F8Val" Value="" />
                            </tr>

                        </table>
```

Example : Q2F8_1 denote Question 2 function 8 and _1 is rating highly disatisfied.

you can use javascript to save 1 , 2 ,3 or 4 to in hidden field which will be your rating for a key .

Access those hidden fields in your c# code and play your code there

Comment: Thank you, but my data is dynamic!

Comment: No problem , its not hard o generate those fields dynamically

Comment: But i don't know how to fill my data to the table :(

Comment: @AIVN you can construct html dynamically in both c# and javascript ,